# Filter Version in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to filter the version in the Get-Command cmdlet.

I've tried:

```
Get-Command -Filter { Version -eq 1.0.1.0}
```

But I doesn't seem to work, does anyone have a solution for that?
 Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: AFAIK does the cmdlet `Get-Command` do not have a parameter `-Filter`. You will have to use a `Where-Object` and filter it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been suggested in the comments - in the absence of a filter option in the cmdlet you will need to filter by piping the results to a where clause as shown

```
Get-Command | Where-Object {$_.Version -eq "1.0.1.0"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
Get-Command | Where-Object Version -eq 1.0.1.0
```